# CSS / JS: How do I tell my page to be completely unselectable, except for stuff inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm doing a live editing thing, but only want certain portions of the page to be selectable. How do I disable selection on everything except within a single div?

Comment: What do you mean by selectable?  Are you trying to disable a form, or all page interaction?

Comment: selectable as in: can highlight any text / objects with the cursor.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Disabling selectability (if that's a word) is very frustrating to the user in most cases.

Comment: yeah, I'm actually doing it on a select few divs to /enhance/ usability. =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the CSS property user-select ?

cross-browser :

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Doc :

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216.html#user-select

<strike>Perhaps you could add the following listeners to the divs / sections you want to prevent selection ?</strike>

```
window.onload = function() {
  var element = document.getElementById('content');
  element.onselectstart = function () { return false; } // ie
  element.onmousedown = function () { return false; } // the rest
}
```

EDIT: See comments

Comment: That's only visually. It doesn't prevent the user from selecting text.

Comment: The CSS method works =\  I pretended to select text. hit ctl c, tried pasting. and the text was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Put a div (positioned absolute) on top of the elements you want to make un-selectable.